# OpenSSL - dependency problem

Tags: apt, openvpn, openssl

I have downloaded the latest version of `openvpn-as` and when I am trying to install it, it shows dependency problem

```
$ sudo dpkg -i openvpn-as-latest-ubuntu18.amd_64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package openvpn-as.
(Reading database ... 166060 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openvpn-as-latest-ubuntu18.amd_64.deb ...
Unpacking openvpn-as (2.8.3-f28d2eae-Ubuntu18) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openvpn-as:
 openvpn-as depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Version of libssl1.1:amd64 on system is 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.
 openvpn-as depends on openvpn-as-bundled-clients; however:
  Package openvpn-as-bundled-clients is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package openvpn-as (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn-as
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
$ apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4
  Candidate: 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I had to install OpenSSL 1.1.1g manually, though, because apt-get has stopped at 1.1.0g.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. My `/etc/apt/sources.list` was broken for some reason.

fix is  [here](https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1)